# how to start celery flower as as daemon in RHEL?

Tags: python, celery, systemd, flower, systemctl

Im trying to run flower as daemon. My flower.service file read as follows:

```
[Unit]

    Description=Flower Service
    After=network.target

[Service]

    Type=forking
    User=maas
    Group=maas
    PermissionsStartOnly=true
    ExecStart=/bin/flower --broker=amqp://oser000300//

[Install]

    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when i start the service, it is giving error.

```
//systemctl status flower.service

* flower.service - Flower Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/flower.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2017-07-10 20:25:59 UTC; 4min 38s ago
  Process: 49255 ExecStart=/bin/flower --broker=amqp://oser000300//  (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)


Connected to amqp://guest:**@oser000300:5672//
flower.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
SIGTERM detected, shutting down
Failed to start Flower Service.
Unit flower.service entered failed state.
flower.service failed.
```

Comment: flower is a monitoring tool for celery (which works using redis), are you running celery ?

Comment: yes, celery is running and im able to run the flower normally but not able to start as a service.

Comment: @jww I think this is a programming question, my question here is about writing service file in shell script or any other form.

Comment: Does `journalctl -b -u flower.service` give any additional details?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same timeout problem when starting the service.

Those parameters has done the trick (i had already celery service running with forking type):

```
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
```